# Order of the zero

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose we consider the following function $f(z) = 1 - e^z$ We want to determine the order of the zeroes of this function here.

My professor wrote that the order of zero of this function is actually 1? how did he determine that ? Can someone explain?

Comment: Do you know how the derivatives of a function and the order of a zero are related?

Comment: Taylor series? ${}{}$

Comment: Yes, they are related by taylor series ?

Comment: What did your professor tell you was the definition of "order of zero"?

Comment: I think I understood what he did he first expanded f(z) in terms of taylor series and counted the order as follows $f(z) = (z - z_0)^kg(z)$ where g(z) is not zero for all disk and we see that order is actually 1 in this case

Comment: I am not sure if I am correct though

Comment: @5xum a point $z_0 \in \theta$ where $\theta$ is our domain for which $f(z) = (z - z_0)^k g(z)$ for some $k \in \mathbb{N}$ and analytic function g on $\theta$ with $g(z) \neq 0$ for all disk of center $z_0$ , is zero of f of order k.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is trivial. The derivative of this function is $-e^z$, which never vanishes. Therefore the function cannot have zeroes of order higher than one.